# Compute outstanding amounts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I am having an issue with a SELECT command in MySQL. I have a database of securities exchanged daily with maturity from 1 to 1000 days (>1 mio rows). I would like to get the outstanding amount per day (and possibly per category). To give an example, suppose this is my initial dataset:

```
DATE    VALUE    MATURITY
1       10       3       
1       15       2
2       10       1
3       5        1
```

I would like to get the following output

```
DATE    OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT
1       25
2       35
3       15
```

Outstanding amount is calculated as the total of securities exchanged still 'alive'. That means, in day 2 there is a new exchange for 10 and two old exchanges (10 and 15) still outstanding as their maturity is longer than one day, for a total outstanding amount of 35 on day 2. In day 3 instead there is a new exchange for 5 and an old exchange from day 1 of 10. That is, 15 of outstanding amount.

Here's a more visual explanation:

```
Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday
10          10          10             (Day 1, Value 10, matures in 3 days)
15          15                         (Day 1, 15, 2 days)
            10                         (Day 2, 10, 1 day)
                        5              (Day 3, 5, 3 days with remainder not shown)
-------------------------------------
25          35          15             (Outstanding amount on each day)
```

Is there a simple way to get this result?

Comment: so what have you tried so far

Comment: so far nothing, as I simply don't have the slightest clue on how to do it. I managed to create a 'bucket' variable by using the CASE command, but this is as far as I went

Comment: how is OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT calculated ?

Comment: *...as I simply don't have the slightest clue on how to do it...* At least explain in detail how does desired output correlate to your sample data

Comment: outstanding amount is calculated as the total of securities exchanged still 'alive'. That means, in day 2 there is a new exchange for 10 and two old exchanges (10 and 15) still outstanding as their maturity is longer than one day, for a total outstanding amount of 35 on day 2. In day 3 instead there is a new exchange for 5 and an old exchange from day 1 of 10. That is, 15 of outstanding amount. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: It looks like @valex has the answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the main subquery we find SUM of all Values for current date. Then add to them values from previous dates according their `MATURITY` (the second subquery).

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/270b7/12)

```
select T1.Date,T1.SumValue+
IFNULL((select SUM(VALUE) 
          from T 
          where 
             T1.Date between 
                T.Date+1 and T.Date+Maturity-1 )
       ,0)
FROM
(
   select Date,
       sum(Value) as SumValue
   from T
   group by Date
) T1
order by DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, perhaps if you give more detail

```
select
   DATE
   ,sum(VALUE) as OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT
from
  NameOfYourTable

group by 
   DATE
Order by
   DATE
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Each date considers each row for inclusion in the summation of value

```
SELECT d.DATE, SUM(m.VALUE) AS OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT
FROM yourTable AS d JOIN yourtable AS m ON d.DATE >= m.MATURITY
GROUP BY d.DATE
ORDER BY d.DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with a tally (numbers) table

```
SELECT date, SUM(value) outstanding_amount
  FROM
(
  SELECT date + maturity - n.n date, value, maturity
    FROM table1 t JOIN
  (
    SELECT 1 n UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 
  ) n ON n.n <= maturity
) q
 GROUP BY date
```

Output:

```
| DATE | OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT |
-----------------------------
|    1 |                 25 |
|    2 |                 35 |
|    3 |                 15 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/993f6/24)** demo